# Get/display the author of a post from another app for notifications system

Tags: python, django

So I am making this notification system that is supposed to show/tell the user when someone else has liked or commented on their post. However, instead of telling the user when someone liked your post it instead records your personal activity and shows all of the likes and comments you yourself have made. I know why this is happening (after all I set it up), I just don't know how to reverse it so the post author get's notified instead of the current user.

I think I have all the info I need, I just don't know how to go into the other apps model, get the extra bit of info I don't have and then display the notifications for/to the post's author. Please help.

Also, please ignore the sloppy imports, I know that needs to be cleaned up.

Notify app views:

```
from django.core.paginator import Paginator,EmptyPage,PageNotAnInteger
from django.shortcuts import render,get_object_or_404,redirect
from django.utils import timezone
from feed.models import UserPost,UserComment
from users.models import UserProfile
from notify.models import UserNotification
from feed.forms import PostForm,CommentForm
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from braces.views import SelectRelatedMixin

from django.views.generic import (TemplateView,ListView,
                                    DetailView,CreateView,
                                    UpdateView,DeleteView,
                                    RedirectView,)

User = get_user_model()

class UserNotifications(LoginRequiredMixin,ListView):
    login_url = 'account_login'
    model = UserNotification
    template_name = 'notify/usernotification_list.html'
    context_object_name = 'notifies'
#   paginate_by = 25

    def get_queryset(self):
        return UserNotification.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)

class NotifyMarkRead(RedirectView):
    def get_redirect_url(self,pk):
        obj = get_object_or_404(UserNotification,pk=pk)
        if obj.read == False:
            obj.read = True
            obj.save()
        else:
            obj.read = False
            obj.save()
        return obj.get_absolute_url()
```

Notify app model:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

User = get_user_model()

# Create your models here.
class UserNotification(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,related_name='user',null=True)
    post = models.ForeignKey('feed.UserPost',related_name='post')
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    notify_type = models.CharField(max_length=6)
    read = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('notify:user_notifications')

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user)
```

Presumably, the way I've set it up, I would need to go in and get the author based on the post recorded in the `UserNotification` model?

Feed app models:

```
from django.db import models
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.conf import settings

from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
User = get_user_model()

# Create your models here.
class UserPost(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User,related_name='userpost',null=True)
    post_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150,blank=False)
    post_body = models.TextField(max_length=1000,blank=False)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='post_pics',blank=True)
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(User,blank=True,related_name='post_likes')

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-post_date']

    def publish(self):
        self.save()

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('index')

    def likes_as_flat_user_id_list(self):
        return self.likes.values_list('id', flat=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

**Update**
Like button view (in Feed app):

```
class LikePostToggle(RedirectView):
    def get_redirect_url(self,pk):
        obj = get_object_or_404(UserPost,pk=pk)
        user = self.request.user
        if user.is_authenticated():
            if user in obj.likes.all():
                obj.likes.remove(user)
            else:
                obj.likes.add(user)
                notification = UserNotification.objects.create(
                    user = self.request.user,
                    post = obj,
                    notify_type = "like",
                )
        return obj.get_absolute_url()
```

The like button works so I didn't show any imports

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should make you code easier the notification system is too easy.
if you want the user to be notified when someone like his post you can do this in the like view

```
def like(request, post):
    post.likes += 1
    post.save()
    notify = post.author
    Notifications_model.objects.create(fromUser=request.user, toUser=notify, content="liked your post")
```

then in your template you can loop through than Notifications like this:

```
{% for notification in filterd_notifications%}
<p>{{notification.fromUser}} {{notification.content}}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

> filterd_notifications is `notifications.objects.filter(toUser=request.user)`

Comment: Which one of my views does this new view replace (or add on to)?

Comment: hi Garrett when i use *likes += 1* this is the same *likes = likes + 1* this will increase the value of likes by one but if you dont know what dose that mean i think you should practice pure python first before django : )

Comment: please update you question and show us your upvote view, how the like button work?

Comment: I undertand Python, I had looked up that operator since I haven't used it since learning python and the explanation was very poorly worded. Thanks for clearing that up. I updated the question to show the like button view.

Comment: thank you for updating your question, as i said before your code *all of it* can be simplified, for example the like view is too big check this out  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46505239/fix-django-views-counter)

Comment: you can check if the user liked the post then upvote, if you didn't get this contact me by email : ), i am waiting : )